# git-p4 submit fails with patch does not apply

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

When I do the following:

```
$ git-p4 submit
```

I wind up with the following error trace:

```
error: patch failed: foo/bar/blah.h:1
error: foo/bar/blah.h: patch does not apply
Unfortunately applying the change failed!
What do you want to do?
[s]kip this patch / [a]pply the patch forcibly and with .rej files / [w]rite the patch to a file (patch.txt)
```

How can I recover from this situation and make a successful submission?

FWIW, our P4 server is configured to use keyword expansion (filetype = text+k) and there is an expanded keyword at line 3 of the problem file. I made a change at line 1.

I've tried removing the delta at line 1, but the error persists when I retry the git-p4 submit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out just after posting this question.

The trick was going in behind P4's back and stripping out the keyword expansion.

```
chmod +w foo/bar/blah.h
edit foo/bar/blah.h #change $File: //depot/foo/bar/blah.h$ to $File$
chmod -w foo/bar/blah.h
git-p4 submit
```

This worked.

Answer (score 1):

This bit me as well.  The other option is to change the file type through the GUI tool or the command line so that it's no longer a `text+k` or `text+ko` file type (so expansion doesn't happen).  If you do that, it will commit OK.