# git p4 submit: patch does not apply

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

Lately I've been running into issues using git-p4.

My current workflow is:

```
git checkout -b some_feature
# do some work and commit to some_feature branch
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff some_feature
git p4 rebase
git p4 submit
```

Not always, but occasionally when executing `git p4 submit`, the changes do not actually apply and instead I see:

```
error: some_file.extension: patch does not apply
```

Doing some research, I've tried doing a hard reset on master and merging again without the `--no-ff` flag, but that doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did either of these work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042865/git-p4-submit-fails-with-patch-does-not-apply
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953609/git-p4-submit-fails

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this issue today. In my case, the problem was because my text editor (Visual Studio) was adding a [Unicode BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) to every file it touched. Meanwhile, the Perforce server was set up to strip the Unicode BOM from every file, preventing a Unicode BOM from appearing in Perforce. This ultimately caused my `git p4 submit` to fail with the following message:

```
error: patch failed: path/to/file.csproj:1
error: path/to/file.csproj: patch does not apply
```

## Final solution

I added the following filter definition in my **~/.gitconfig** file:

```
[filter "utf8-autobom"]
        clean = sed -b -e '1!b' -e 's/^\\xEF\\xBB\\xBF//'
        smudge = sed -b -e '1!b' -e 's/\\(^\\|^\\xEF\\xBB\\xBF\\)/\\xEF\\xBB\\xBF/'
```

Then I applied the `utf8-autobom` filter to the offending files by adding the following line in **.gitattributes**:

```
*.csproj filter=utf8-autobom
```

Then I forced Git to apply the filter to its index with:

```
rm .git/index
git reset
```

Then I committed the edited files to Git and submitted my commit to Perforce as usual:

```
git add .
git commit --amend
git p4 submit
```

## How it works

The filter definition is based on the following `sed` commands, where "abc" is a placeholder for the appropriate Unicode BOM byte sequence:

```
# Remove 'abc' from beginning of file, if present
sed -b -e '1!b' -e 's/^abc//'

# Add 'abc' to beginning of file, if not present
sed -b -e '1!b' -e 's/\(^\|^abc\)/abc/'
```

For a UTF-8 BOM, we use the byte sequence `EF BB BF` instead of "abc".

The filter removes the BOM on commit by running the `clean` command, and adds the BOM on checkout by running the `smudge` command. This keeps the BOM in the working tree files, but prevents the BOM from being committed to Git, or submitted to Perforce.

*(Refer to the [gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#__code_filter_code) for details on `clean` and `smudge`.)*

## Diagnosing the problem

I thought the error message was interesting:

```
error: patch failed: path/to/file.csproj:1
error: path/to/file.csproj: patch does not apply
```

It said the patch failed on line 1 even though my commit didn't edit line 1 of the file.

To see what was going on, I ran `git diff p4/master HEAD`. The diff showed that my commit was adding a strange `<U+FEFF>` character at the beginning of the file. I suspected it was related to file encoding, so I used Notepad++ to open the file in my Git working tree. Then I opened the corresponding file in my Perforce workspace. Notepad++ showed the encoding as "UTF-8-BOM" in my Git working tree, and "UTF-8" in my Perforce workspace. *(Linux and Cygwin users: use the `file <path-to-file>` command to show information about file encoding.)*

Googling "UTF-8-BOM" got me on the right path.

## Notice

Some Git operations will be slower with this filter installed.

## Tip

You can remove the `smudge` portion of the filter if you don't need the BOM in your working tree. This will speed up some Git operations (like `git checkout`). With the `smudge` line removed, the filter definition is:

```
[filter "utf8-autobom"]
        clean = sed -b -e '1!b' -e 's/^\\xEF\\xBB\\xBF//'
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem and I think the root cause was the line endings. You can try to run stuff like `dos2unix` to fix it, or set this config:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Sometimes, file modes can cause problems to. This config can fix it (if you don't care about file modes):

```
git config core.filemode false
```

Answer (score 2):

From [jlapolla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6815417/jlapolla)'s [2016 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39421876/6309)

> Then I applied the `utf8-autobom` filter

Such a filter might not be needed anymore with Git 2.37 (Q3 2022)

See [commit fbe5f6b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbe5f6b80437adbcd58af1b3751b830910a2ddaa) (04 Apr 2022) by [Tao Klerks (`TaoK`)](https://github.com/TaoK).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 804ec03](https://github.com/git/git/commit/804ec0301fddb68d5170939084d79e2c0c672028), 20 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbe5f6b80437adbcd58af1b3751b830910a2ddaa): preserve utf8 BOM when importing from p4 to git
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tao Klerks</sup>

> Perforce has a file type "`utf8`" which represents a text file with explicit BOM.
> `utf8-encoded` files *without* BOM are stored as regular file type "`text`".
> The "`utf8`" file type behaves like text in all but one important way: it is stored, internally, without the leading 3 BOM bytes.
>
> `git-p4` has historically imported `utf8-with-BOM` files (files stored, in Perforce, as type "`utf8`") the same way as regular `text` files - *losing* the BOM in the process.
>
> Under most circumstances this issue has little functional impact, as most systems consider the BOM to be optional and redundant, but this *is* a correctness failure, and can have lead to practical issues for example when BOMs are explicitly included in test files, for example in a file encoding test suite.
>
> Fix the handling of `utf8-with-BOM` files when importing changes from `p4` to Git, and introduce a test that checks it is working correctly.

That means:

> The type utf8 explicitly means utf8 *with BOM*.
> These are streamed just like regular text files, however, without the BOM in the stream.
>
> Therefore, to accurately import these files into git, we need to explicitly re-add the BOM before writing.
> '`contents`' is a set of bytes in this case, so create the BOM prefix as a `b''` literal.

So a `p4 submit -d "add utf8 test files"` followed by `git p4 clone --dest="$git" //depot@all` should give utf-8 files in the Git repository, with BOM preserved.

---

Furthermore, still with Git 2.37 (Q3 2022):

See [commit f7b5ff6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7b5ff607fa1a62a480399afb6ccb9691735bf79) (30 Apr 2022) by [Tao Klerks (`TaoK`)](https://github.com/TaoK).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3af1df0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3af1df0415741c85f84e78e281339186be1d05d7), 20 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7b5ff607fa1a62a480399afb6ccb9691735bf79): improve encoding handling to support inconsistent encodings
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tao Klerks</sup>

> `git-p4` is designed to run correctly under python2.7 and python3, but its functional behavior wrt importing user-entered text differs across these environments:
>
> Under python2, `git-p4` "naively" writes the Perforce bytestream into git metadata (and does not set an "encoding" header on the commits); this means that any non-utf-8 byte sequences end up creating invalidly-encoded commit metadata in git.
>
> Under python3, `git-p4` attempts to decode the Perforce bytestream as utf-8 data, and fails badly (with an unhelpful error) when non-utf-8 data is encountered.
>
> Perforce clients (especially `p4v`) encourage user entry of changelist descriptions (and user full names) in OS-local encoding, and store the resulting bytestream to the server unmodified - such that different clients can end up creating mutually-unintelligible messages.
> The most common inconsistency, in many Perforce environments, is likely to be utf-8 (typical in linux) vs cp-1252 (typical in windows).
>
> Make the `changelist-description-` and `user-fullname-handling` code python-runtime-agnostic, introducing three "strategies" selectable via config:
>
> - 'passthrough', behaving as previously under python2,
> - 'strict', behaving as previously under python3, and
> - 'fallback', favoring utf-8 but supporting a secondary encoding when> utf-8 decoding fails, and finally escaping high-range bytes if the decoding with the secondary encoding also fails.
>
> Keep the python2 default behavior as-is ('legacy' strategy), but switch the python3 default strategy to 'fallback' with default fallback encoding 'cp1252'.

`git p4` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f7b5ff607fa1a62a480399afb6ccb9691735bf79/Documentation/git-p4.txt#L639-L674):

> ### `git-p4.metadataDecodingStrategy`
>
> Perforce keeps the encoding of a changelist descriptions and user
> full names as stored by the client on a given OS. The p4v client
> uses the OS-local encoding, and so different users can end up storing
> different changelist descriptions or user full names in different
> encodings, in the same depot.
>
> Git tolerates inconsistent/incorrect encodings in commit messages
> and author names, but expects them to be specified in utf-8.
> git-p4 can use three different decoding strategies in handling the
> encoding uncertainty in Perforce:
>
> - 'passthrough' simply passes the
>   original bytes through from Perforce to git, creating usable but
>   incorrectly-encoded data when the Perforce data is encoded as
>   anything other than utf-8.
> - 'strict' expects the Perforce data to be
>   encoded as utf-8, and fails to import when this is not true.
> - 'fallback' attempts to interpret the data as utf-8, and otherwise
>   falls back to using a secondary encoding - by default the common
>   windows encoding 'cp-1252' - with upper-range bytes escaped if
>   decoding with the fallback encoding also fails.
>
> Under python2 the default strategy is 'passthrough' for historical
> reasons, and under python3 the default is 'fallback'.
> When 'strict' is selected and decoding fails, the error message will
> propose changing this config parameter as a workaround. If this
> option is passed into a `p4 clone` request, it is persisted into the
> resulting new git repo.
>
> ### `git-p4.metadataFallbackEncoding`
>
> Specify the fallback encoding to use when decoding Perforce author
> names and changelists descriptions using the 'fallback' strategy
> (see `git-p4.metadataDecodingStrategy`).
> The fallback encoding will
> only be used when decoding as utf-8 fails.
>
> This option defaults to
> cp1252, a common windows encoding.
> If this option is passed into a
> `p4 clone` request, it is persisted into the resulting new git repo.